# Bas rights on a folder when I automount an hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, mount, permissions, fstab

I want to automount an hard drive when my raspberry pi zero starts. The commands works but I can't write in the folder because I don't have permission even if I use sudo. I can only read. I already tried to change folder's permission with *chmod* but the problem persists. According to the *man*, I think it's the good command.
This is the line I added to fstab file :

```
UUID=My-UUID /mnt/myFolder ntfs,auto,umask=000,users,rw 0 0
```

**Edit :**

If I add the line `UUID=MY-UUID /mnt/MY-FOLDER ntfs rw,noauto,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8 0 0` on my fstab file and I exectute the command `sudo mount -a` or I reboot the raspberry, the hard drive is not mounted but I have not an error message. So I don't have the permission problem because the disk is not mounted...

Answer (score 2):

Your `fstab` entry is incorrect. It should be something like:-

```
UUID=       /mnt/SeagateBackupPlus     ntfs    rw,noauto,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8 0   0
UUID=       /mnt/PiData     ext4    defaults,noatime,noauto  0     0
```

Under `Stretch` you may need to install `ntfs-3g` to enable writing to NTFS

I have added a typical `ext4` drive entry. NOTE I invariably manually mount, rather than automount.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but can you edit it to mount in ext4 ? I changed my mind and I want to use ext4. I added the command `UUID=MY-UUID /mnt/MY-FOLDER ext4 rw,noauto,relatime,umask=22,uid=0,gid=0,nls=utf8 0 0` and `sudo mount -a` to test without rebooting but it doesn't mount disk. Also, is it possible to add an option to boot even if the hard drive is unpluged ? Thanks.

Comment: @Anonyme I have added an entry I use for `ext4` . This I use for Pi backups, but rather than automount, I manage mounts in my scripts.

Comment: When I add the entry for ext4 type hard drive, I can mount it with the command `sudo mount /dev/sda` and it will automatically mount in the specified folder in the fstab file. But the original question is how to mount automatically an ext4 hard drive with the fstab file ? I don't want to use a script. Why when I replace `ntfs` by `ext4` in the command you give me it doesn't works ? Thanks.

Comment: @Anonyme You should add additional detail to your question, rather than in Comments. NOTE you now appear to be asking a different question, which is strictly off-topic for this site, and is a generic Linux question. Most of these can be resolved by reading `man mount`, but no one can give you an entry to suit all uses. Also "doesn't work" is not helpful, you need to explain what doesn't and/or list error messges. I don't use automount, because my `fstab` has dozens of entries, and testing for non-existent drives delays boot.

Comment: Ok, I will open a new subject for ext4. I will focus on NTFS hard drive for this subject. Actually, the problem persists, I just edited the original message.